# AppFabric and Distributed Cache sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, distributedcache, app-fabric

We have been experiencing intermittent problems for users that access SharePoint 2013. Sometimes the images are distorted and other times some sites do not render. Error 'something went wrong' appears with a correlation ID. Recently I had to perform iisreset which did not restore normal functionality, then re-booted server which worked. I need to find a fix before the problem repeats itself. (its been ongoing before I took the job on)

I've tracked this down in the events and the error points to the distributed cache I think. **Is there anything else I should be checking for?**

```
05/22/2017 14:56:02.50  w3wp.exe (0x102C)                           0x1904  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4a   Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed cache for '0).w|s-1-5-21-862529981-1745561597-965413785-17542'.(This is expected during the process warm up or if data cache Initialization is getting done by some other thread).    e529f49d-7d34-405f-8d6e-1faeb186771c
```

The current version of AppFabric that's installed on the wfe and App server is v1.1 (1.1.2106.32), CU1

We are running 1 WFE and 1 APP server.

Under windows services > WFE  > AppFabric Caching Service - set to Automatic and on App Server it is disabled.

SharePoint > Services on Server >WFE >Distributed Cache - Started
 SharePoint > Services on Server >APP >Distributed Cache is not listed

The link below lists CU with latest being CU7. I wanted to confirm which CU I should be looking at installing?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3092423/cumulative-update-7-for-microsoft-appfabric-1.1-for-windows-serverI 
 Think we have .net 4.5 already installed, both servers need windows security updates also and the last CU  SharePoint CU 15.0.4779.1000   -   ​​December 2015  -

Can I install the AppFabric CU before SharePoint CU's or is the Appfabric CU already included in one of the SharePoint CU's?

Thanks

Comment: You have at least 4 questions here: How to fix distorted/not appearing images; where to look for logs/output; which CU should be installed; and can AppFabric CU be installed or is it pre-installed. You will more likely receive helpful answers if you can clarify your question and scope your question to actually include only one question.

Comment: Agreed, but the reason is that one answer may affect the other and this is the reason why I've added more information.